# Xamarin.iOS: How to add new ViewControllers to TabBarController FROM CODE, with each ViewController having its own .storyboard for UI?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have a `UITabBarController` called `MainView`, in `MainView.storyboard`. I have 2 other `UIViewController`s called `ChildOneView` and `ChildTwoView`, each in their own `.storyboard`s, `ChildOneView.storyboard` and `ChildTwoView.storyboard`.

`MainView.storyboard` has only a `TabBar` and nothing else. Each `Child` storyboard contains only a `Label` with its name. There is no segue whatsoever; navigation is intended to be managed by MvvmCross.

What I want to achieve, and has no idea how to, is from `MainView.cs`, instantiate `ChildOneView` and `ChildTwoView` as new tab items in `MainView`, with `ChildOneView` and `ChildTwoView` having their UI loaded from their corresponding `.storyboard`s. The navigation is managed by MvvmCross.

I have searched for an answer for doing those things from code, but I've only found ones that were about using a single storyboard with segues. Any tips on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From code, you can create a new instance from different storyboard with:

```
UIStoryboard childOneSb = UIStoryboard.FromName("ChildOneView", null);
UIStoryboard childTwoSb = UIStoryboard.FromName("ChildTwoView", null);
```

Then you can create a new instance of your ViewControllers with:

```
ChildOneView_VC vc1 = childOneSb.InstantiateViewController("ChildOneView") as ChildOneView;
ChildTwoView_VC vc2 = childTwoSb.InstantiateViewController("ChildTwoView") as ChildTwoView;
```

And then you can put them in your `UITabBarController`.

PS: Remember to put `ChildOneView` and `ChildTwoView` as Storyboard ID in with XCode or Xamarin Designer

Comment: "put them in your `UITabBarController`" -> how can I do this? (Sorry, I'm still new to iOS). I tried in `MainView.ViewDidLoad()` for `TabBarController.AddChildViewController(ViewController)` but `TabBarController` is returning null.

Comment: You need to subclass `UITabBarController` and add your VCs to its `ViewControllers` property. You can find a good example [at this link (official Xamarin documentation)](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/tab_bar/create_a_tab_bar/)